# apply_filters('the_content', $content) alternative

Tags: filters, the-content

"the_content" filter can get added with other filters from plugins and themes which could alter content, when you simply want this to format the post_content to HTML format.

Is there a better solution for this that other plugins do not add filters to and can format the post content to HTML format just like this filter do?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. If another plugin is changing that filter in a way you don't like, uninstall it. That filter is the best way to filter the content for output. Especially if you developing a public plugin. Don't try to reinvent the wheel in a way that cause it to not work as expected.

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Do you want to remove filters from the content, or do you wish to use similar (but not all) filters on other content (such as post meta, or theme options)?

Answer (score 8):

[The Core filters on `the_content` are](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L131):

```
131 add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'        );
132 add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
133 add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars'      );
134 add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
135 add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
136 add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

You can apply whichever of those you'd like to any string you'd like. The second parameter is the name of a function which takes a string as input, so...

```
$str = 'this is my content';
$str = wptexturize($str);
$str = convert_smilies($str);
$str = wpautop($str);
```

And so on. Use the ones you want. Ignore the others. That should give you plenty of control. Plugins cannot hook in if there is no hook, but be careful robbing a theme of expected functionality is unfriendly and could break things.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/convert_smilies
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Comment: That makes sense, what I was doing is:

$str = 'the text content';
$str = apply_filters('the_content',$str);

Comment: `convert_smiles` should be `convert_smilies`